# Getting Exception on Surface Change

Tags: google-cardboard, rajawalivr

Got the below stacktrace as part of Crash Report.

It looks like this problem is specific to one type of device OnePlusOne.
Any pointers will be helpful.

Anyone if want to test the app on device its [VR Photo Viewer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lazybuds.vrphotoviewer)

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bitmap is recycled
at android.opengl.GLUtils.texImage2D(GLUtils.java:112)
at org.rajawali3d.materials.textures.ASingleTexture.add(ASingleTexture.java:186)
at org.rajawali3d.materials.textures.TextureManager.taskAdd(TextureManager.java:110)
at org.rajawali3d.materials.textures.TextureManager.taskReload(TextureManager.java:209)
at org.rajawali3d.renderer.RajawaliRenderer.onRenderSurfaceSizeChanged(RajawaliRenderer.java:362)
at org.rajawali3d.vr.renderer.RajawaliVRRenderer.onSurfaceChanged(RajawaliVRRenderer.java:88)
at com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.CardboardViewJavaImpl$StereoRendererHelper.onSurfaceChanged(CardboardViewJavaImpl.java:931)
at com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.CardboardViewJavaImpl$RendererHelper.onSurfaceChanged(CardboardViewJavaImpl.java:716)
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1511)
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1239)
```

**UPDATE 1**

Reported in github: https://github.com/Rajawali/RajawaliVR/issues/15

Comment: you are using your bitmap after recycling it. either use it before recycling or create new bitmap and use. you can avoid recycling but its bad practice.

Comment: The stack trace does not points to any method from my code, thus I am confused which Bitmap image is recycled. All file in stack are part of the framework.

Comment: I would suggest fork the library and then comment the line which recycles the bitmap by looking at the above stack trace, you can always deploy it again with your app by building and then test. Its just suggestion and it may not be feasible sometime.